# How do I exclude a subdirectory during get with psftp?

Tags: ssh, sftp, putty, psftp

I am using the PuTTY psftp `get` command to download files recursively from a remote Unix server to my local PC and I need to exclude the `vendor` subdirectory.

The vendor folder lives under `/var/www/html/project/` together with other files and folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

psftp does not have such functionality.

---

You would have to use another SFTP client. For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/), you can use `-filemask` switch of its [`get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get):

```
get -filemask=|vendor/ /remote/path/* C:\local\path\
```

There is also a [guide for converting PSFTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_psftp_script_to_winscp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*